# How to add multiple pictures in Word from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, ms-word, dispose

I'm trying to add multiple pictures in a word document using vb.net but on the second picture, trhows the following error: *System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'*, I think I might dispose some variable but I don't know which.
this is my code:

```
Sub LoadPics()

    Dim wdWrapFront As Integer = 3
    Dim wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage As Integer = 1

    Dim objWordApp As Word.Application
    objWordApp = New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSelection

    objDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open("Document.doc")

    Dim objShapes As Word.InlineShapes
    objShapes = objDoc.InlineShapes
    Dim oShape As Word.Shape

    objWordApp.Visible = False

    objSelection = objWordApp.Selection
    Dim FL As string = ""

    For c As Integer = 0 to 10
                FL = "file.png"
                If IO.File.Exists(FL) Then

                    oShape = objShapes.AddPicture(FL).ConvertToShape()'<<<---here is the problem

                    With oShape
                        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapFront
                        .LockAspectRatio = False
                        .Height = objWordApp.CentimetersToPoints(5.08)
                        .Width = objWordApp.CentimetersToPoints(10.16)
                        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
                        .Top = objWordApp.CentimetersToPoints(TopValue)
                        .Left = objWordApp.CentimetersToPoints(LeftValue)
                    End With

                Else
                    MsgBox("File doesn't exist" & vbCrLf & FL)
                End If
    Next

    objWordApp.Visible = True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by simply changing this line

```
objWordApp.Visible = True
```

I don't know which was the problem with that line but it works now